# cmp DWORD [ebp - 25], [ebp + 12] is causing an error

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

The following instruction is causing an `invalid combination of opcode and operands` error:

```
cmp DWORD [ebp - 25], [ebp + 12]
```

I thought that the `DWORD` is used to prevent such an error!

I also tried the following but still the same error:

```
cmp DWORD [ebp - 25], DWORD [ebp + 12]
```

Comment: You should really read the manual, it answers simple questions like this (and one of your previous questions) so you don't have to waste your time asking them on the internet.

Comment: BTW, in addition to the answers: how did you achieve having _dword_ at an odd address?

Comment: @Netch I have created a 1 byte variable before `ebp - 25`, should I `sub esp, 3` after this 1 byte allocation?

Comment: @Steve on x86, you shouldn't unless you want to gain performance improvement due to properly aligned data, but this isn't strict requirement. OTOH, stack pointer itself shall be aligned at least for the current mode address size, so, allocating 1 byte with decreasing stack pointer by 1 is an extremely bad manner and could cause immediate exception in some environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, on x86, memory-to-memory operations are not supported.

You need to first load one of the arguments into a register. Then you can compare that register content to another memory location. E.g:

```
mov eax, DWORD [ebp - 25] 
cmp eax, [ebp + 12]
```